# Using local authentication inside Future builder is calling local authentication infinite number of times after authenticating

Tags: flutter, authentication, local, future, builder

I am trying to use local authentication to authenticate the user before he uses the app . But the problem is that I have to use Future Builder for checking user data to go to Home Screen or Login Screen According. Therefore, I have to use local authentication inside Future Builder to authenticate user. But this results in calling fingerprint auth infinite times after I reach to home screen also. So We can't get rid of local auth. Please help and tell if there is another way around . Thanks In Advance :)

```
 class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
    }
    
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      final AuthMethods _authMethods = AuthMethods();
      final LocalAuthentication _localAuthentication = LocalAuthentication();
      bool _hasFingerPrintSupport = false;
      bool _authorizedOrNot = false;
      List<BiometricType> _availableBuimetricType = List<BiometricType>();
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _getBiometricsSupport();
        _getAvailableSupport();
      }
    
      Future<void> _getBiometricsSupport() async {
        bool hasFingerPrintSupport = false;
        try {
          hasFingerPrintSupport = await _localAuthentication.canCheckBiometrics;
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
        if (!mounted) return;
        setState(() {
          _hasFingerPrintSupport = hasFingerPrintSupport;
        });
      }
        Future<void> _getAvailableSupport() async {
    
        List<BiometricType> availableBuimetricType = List<BiometricType>();
        try {
          availableBuimetricType =
              await _localAuthentication.getAvailableBiometrics();
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
        if (!mounted) return;
        setState(() {
          _availableBuimetricType = availableBuimetricType;
        });
      }
    
      Future<void> _authenticateMe() async {
     
        bool authenticated = false;
        try {
          authenticated = await _localAuthentication.authenticateWithBiometrics(
            localizedReason: "Authenticate to use App", // message for dialog
            useErrorDialogs: true,// show error in dialog
            stickyAuth: false,// native process
          );
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
        if (!mounted) return;
        setState(() {
          _authorizedOrNot = authenticated ? true : false;
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final themeNotifier = Provider.of<ThemeNotifier>(context);
      _authenticateMe();
        return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (_) => ThemeNotifier(darkTheme),
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ImageUploadProvider()),
            ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (_) => VideoUploadProvider(),
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => UserProvider()),
          ],
          child: MaterialApp(
            title: "App",
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            initialRoute: '/',
            routes: {
              '/search_screen': (context) => SearchScreen(),
              '/setting_page': (context) => settingPage(),
            },
            theme: themeNotifier.getTheme(),
            home: FutureBuilder(
              future: _authMethods.getCurrentUser(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
                   
                if (snapshot.hasData ) {
                   return _authorizedOrNot==true ? HomeScreen() : Container(); 
                } else {
                  return LoginScreen();
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: You should try to separate more your logic and your view by using a state manager. For example, you dispatch an event that will check the user data, and depending the result you will change the state of the view or make the redirection. There is many ways to do that in Flutter by using providers, blocs or redux for example. Good luck to you !

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case you call `_authenticateMe();` at the beginning of your build().

`_authenticateMe();` has inside a setState that cause build() to refire again and call `_authenticateMe();` thus rebuilding thus rebuilding.

P.S. I would move the FutureBuilder up until is over the MaterialApp, it may cause problem with the use of the hot reload.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out a way around by calling the authenticate function in init state and then checking for isauthorizedorNot before returning Future builder .
Here is the code :-

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
final LocalAuthentication _localAuthentication = LocalAuthentication();
    final AuthMethods _authMethods = AuthMethods();
  bool _authorizedOrNot ;

  Future<void> _authenticateMe() async {
    bool authenticated = false;
    try {
      authenticated = await _localAuthentication.authenticateWithBiometrics(
        localizedReason: "Authenticate to use app", 
        useErrorDialogs: true,

        stickyAuth: false, 
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      _authorizedOrNot = authenticated ? true : false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
   
    super.initState();
    _authenticateMe();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 
    final themeNotifier = Provider.of<ThemeNotifier>(context);
    
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => ThemeNotifier(darkTheme),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ImageUploadProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => VideoUploadProvider(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => UserProvider()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: "App",
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: {
          '/search_screen': (context) => SearchScreen(),
          '/setting_page': (context) => settingPage(),
        },
        theme: themeNotifier.getTheme(),
        home: _authorizedOrNot==true ?  FutureBuilder(
          future: _authMethods.getCurrentUser(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
 
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return HomeScreen();
             
            } else {
              return LoginScreen();
            
            }
          },
        )  : ( Container(child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),)
      ),)
    );
  }
}
```